# Android: When keyboard pops up, how to stop MapView and buttons from moving up?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, onclicklistener, searchview

EDIT: When I used to click on searchView, my buttons would appear above the keyboard. Then I was told on stackOverflow to use the following code:

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode=“adjustNothing"
```

or

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Placed the above code in AndroidManifest.xml under  `android:name=".MainActivity"`

Now the buttons don't jump above the keyboard but they still do jump a little. It seems to me the jump is still affected by the rise of the 3 Android buttons at bottom of screen (home, back, 3rd button) that rise along with keyboard (At least that's how it works on my Samsung Galaxy Note 8).

Is there a code that goes in AndroidManifest.xml that also states that when the 3 android buttons (home, back, 3rd button) rise with keyboard, the buttons/labels and mapView won't rise along with it?

(Not using scrollView and using Constraint Layout.)

Comment: Does it solve your problem if you add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` to your activity's entry in your manifest?

Comment: @BenP. , your code works in manifest for the keyboard. However, I still get the buttons to jump now, they don't jump above keyboard anymore but they still jump a little I think it's due to the 3 android buttons at bottom (home, back, and 3rd), when they raise with the keyboard, the buttons still raise just a bit. How to make the buttons stop rising when those 3 android buttons appear with keyboard?